# Tracking points: insert or update?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, database-design

I am adding a points system to my app where for every action a user takes (signup, vote, comment, etc), they get awarded points.  Since its a fairly common feature, I wanted to get a sense of how others have implemented their points system.

More specifically, when tracking points, whether you are doing new inserts into a points table and then just doing a SUM whenever you need the total, or if you are updating a single entry for each user.  What key factors would sway a decision one way over the other, and what are the trade-offs?

Intuitively, since inserts are generally cheaper than updates, I would think that inserts is the way to go assuming that the avg number of points per user isn't too high.  However, I am no db expert, so I would love to get your thoughts.

Comment: Please don't ask for opinions/discussions, this is not a forum - see the [faq].

Answer (score 0):

> What key factors would sway a decision one way over the other, and
>   what are the trade-offs?

Performance may not factor into it. The main swayer will probably be whether or not you want to keep track of how the points were awarded. A user may want to go back and review his actions and subsequent points. In that case, you'll need to keep track of each awarding in some way.

With that in mind, you should be leaning towards some sort of points table with a row per user/awarding.